# How to write english from right to left in a text area

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, right-to-left

I have a very simple question related to writing in text areas. When I set the dir=RTL for the page and I write in English, the browser or the textarea would write the words from left to right like any English writer would, but I want it to write the words from right to left. Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Current Behavior:
بشم Test [this] دجاج

Expected Behavior:
بشم [this] Test دجاج

Note: I am writing from right to left

Comment: English isn't a RTL language. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `<textarea dir="rtl"></textarea>`? or do you want to reveres the typing?

Comment: When I am typing in both Arabic and English, it writes it correctly moving from right to left, but when I write two consecutive English words, it writes them to the right while I want them to behave like the Arabic/Hebrew writing direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of a RTL textbox treats multiple English words separated by spaces as a "left-to-right run", thus rendering it as a mini English sentence (LTR) within the larger RTL text. That's why you see those English words render from left to right.

To bypass this default behavior we can catch the space characters, which are neutral characters that inherit their directionality from the previous word, and add a special invisible Unicode control character called `Right-to-Left Mark` (RLM). This character acts like an Arabic character but has no visual representation. It will just make every word (no matter which language) start with an invisible Arabic character, which will make the browser render it on the left side of the previous word.

To add RLM characters while typing:

```js
function setWordOrder(e) {
 if (e.key == " ") {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
  textbox.value += "\u200F";
 }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea" style="direction: rtl" onkeyup="setWordOrder(event)"></textarea>
```

If you save this text to a database you can remove the RLM characters before saving, so that your data is "pure". If you later want to display an existing text from the database (without the user typing it) you can add RLM characters yourself after each space character, before displaying the text on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea dir="rtl">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 thing 
Use direction:RTL for the RIGHT alignment

`<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;"`

then write a JavaScript handler that will attach to the event: "onkeyup", which performs the shifting of the entered character to the LEFT

```
 function rtl(element)
     {   
      if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
     }
    }
    onkeyup="rtl(this);
```

check out the snippet

```js
function rtl(element)
{   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" onkeyup="rtl(this);"/>
```

Comment: The behavior when you move from right to left for each word is somewhat I want, but I do not want to reverse the English words. I think if I add style="direction:RTL;" it will work. I will try now.